# Six-letter word with four unique vowels

Tags: riddle, word

Can you find the English word that meets all of the following criteria?

- six letters long (non-hyphenated)
- four unique vowels
- two unique consonants
- starts and ends in a vowel
- when you remove the vowels, you see through them

Comment: What do you mean by see through
 them?

Comment: If the remaining consonants were "mt" (=empty) you could see through it. I don't think this is right, because OP says "them", but maybe something like that?

Comment: I wonder why this riddle is highly downvoted.

Comment: @JamalSenjaya That's because it sucked at first :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on the word list in [Laurel's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/57361/17297), my answer is:

> opaque.

Because, when you remove the vowels, you have:

> pq, which resembles a  pair of glasses, thus meeting the *see through* criteria.

Comment: Yep. There's also a link with the word and what you're left with, if you wanted to mention that.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure about seeing *through* them, but removing vowels from

> **OUTVIE**

... leaves you something you can look *at* ...

Comment: *through* is important

Comment: Is that... Even a word? Nevermind, this IS English we're talking about. I'd love it if you included a definition, though.

Answer (score 2):

Well, now that there is no [no-computers](/questions/tagged/no-computers), I hacked together some code. I used `/usr/share/dict/words` as my dictionary. We know that it starts and ends with a vowel, is six letters long, and all the letters are different, so the word must match this regex:

> `^([aeiou])(?!\1)(.)(?!\1)(?!\2)(.)(?!\1)(?!\2)(?!\3)(.)(?!\1)(?!\2)(?!\3)(?!\4)(.)(?!\1)(?!\2)(?!\3)(?!\4)(?!\5)[aeiou]$`

We know it must have 4 vowels, which means it will also match this regex:

> `([aeiou].*?[aeiou].*?[aeiou].*?[aeiou])`

This got me this list:

> acoine
>  
>  aerugo
>  
>  agouti
>  
>  ailuro
>  
>  alpieu
>  
>  apiole
>  
>  apiose
>  
>  apoise
>  
>  aquose
>  
>  areito
>  
>  arigue
>  
>  ariose
>  
>  arouse
>  
>  asideu
>  
>  audile
>  
>  augite
>  
>  aumrie
>  
>  auntie
>  
>  auride
>  
>  aurite
>  
>  embuia
>  
>  epizoa
>  
>  iodate
>  
>  ipomea
>  
>  obelia
>  
>  ogaire
>  
>  opaque
>  
>  opiate
>  
>  oturia
>  
>  outage
>  
>  outawe
>  
>  outlie
>  
>  outsea
>  
>  outvie
>  
>  uniate
>  
>  ureido
>  
>  uremia
>  
>  utopia

The last clue ("when you remove the vowels, you see through them") isn't as easily cracked. I have some guesses:

> outsea -> "sea" is through when you remove the vowels
>  uremia -> remove vowels to get [rm](https://askubuntu.com/q/670648)
>  utopia -> remove vowels to get "tp" or toilet paper. The promise of utopia is replaced by something you flush away

Comment: Nice regex. You don't have the correct answer though

Answer (score 0):

Surely there are many such words? But one example is

> GUINEA.

Comment: Its been updated